# Retrieve last command when Chaining

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh, command-history

When chaining commands in zsh using `;`, `&&` and `||`, how can I access the previous command in chain (the command that is being executed before)?
Example:

```
rm foo ; echo ...
```

In place of the dots, I'm looking for some kind of command / variable that provides me with `rm foo`.

I have tried playing around a bit with `history` and `!!`, but those only provide the commands up until the command that was executed last, not the current one.
Another idea was to use `$0`, but this only prints the location of zsh.

Accessing the complete chain would also be fine, if retrieving only the last command is not possible.

Comment: if you just want to enable printing of the commands executed, that can be implemented differently!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I want to pass the command to another command down the line, specifically I want to use `ntfy` to send a notification with the command and status

Comment: that sounds a lot like you'd architecturally should rather write a function that takes the command as argument, executes and saves it for later (or logs it right away?), rather than trying to retrieve it after the fact!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I thought that it would be good for ease of use to just have an alias that I can put at the end of a command, and then it takes care of notifying me. A function would be my alternative if this doesn't work out

Comment: I'd say it's a bit surprising to put something after something, when you actually want to apply it as an operation on it! In languages like shell languages, you typically have "function arguments..." not "arguments; function".

Comment: @MarcusMüller I agree, it's a bit counterintuitive. For me, it's an ease of use thing, because I can just write whatever command I want and then decide to be notified at the end. This is also pretty similar with what you'd normally do with ntfy: `rm foo; ntfy send finished`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
$ TRAPDEBUG() last_command=$current_command current_command=$ZSH_DEBUG_CMD
$ echo test; print -r -- $last_command
test
echo test
```

Beware there will be some reformatting of the commands:

```
$ (echo test); print -r -- $last_command
test
(
        echo test
)
$ (for a (1 2) echo $a); print -r -- $last_command
1
2
(
        for a in 1 2
        do
                echo $a
        done
)
```